# Randomly display post based on meta value. (Kind of Priority/Weight)

Tags: loop, meta-query

First of all, I haven't tried anything yet because I really don't know where to start.

I am trying to randomly display a post (from a CPT) based on a meta value (a numeric meta value from 1 to 10) which should act like a priority/weight. Higher the value is, higher the chance to display that post.

I believe this can not be achieved using standard WordPress loop and this is exactly where my researches are getting lost.

How can I do this? Any help or point of direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

hell yes you can do this with a standard `WP_Query`. As far as i understand, all you need is a random number between 1 and 10 (or so) and then fetch a random post with that specific number `> meta_query`. So all you need is a logic, that creates your random number, preferably the lower, the more often..

```
floor(abs(random() - random()) * (1 + max - min) + min)
```

[credits](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116832/random-number-in-a-range-biased-toward-the-low-end-of-the-range)